# Monitor if new software updates/versions are available

Tags: windows, update

I am managing 200+ Windows 7 machines with 150+ applications installed and would like to find an easy way to monitor if there is new software version/update available. I use SCCM+WSUS+SCUP for Windows and Adobe updates, but I don't have any way to monitor other applications.

For the moment I use RSS to gather information about some of the updates, which is not very convenient.

Is there an easy way to do it? Ideally an application which can automatically connect to software providers and gather all info...

Comment: There are tools like Secunia CSI, but likely they don't include everything that might be worth checking, as they can't possible know about all kinds of software in use.

Answer (score 1):

This product doesn't exist, and those that claim to do it are incomplete. This is one of the bigger pain points for Windows administration as there is no central 'repo' that all software ends up in. RSS feeds and subscriptions are some of the best tools for managing the non-MS update problem.